How to get VTK working with G++ on linux?
I'm trying to build the VTK, I followed the steps from the GitHub Build Page but I can't locate the header files.
Where are those located?
And also where is the lib which I can pass to g++ while compiling.
It has generated some files in the lib folder but I'm confused which to use with g++.
Here is what's inside the lib folder
I'm running red hat enterprise linux, with AMD cpu and Nvidia GPU.
So far I have done this
mkdir vtk && cd vtk/
git clone https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk.git

Make sure git repo is updated
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master

mkdir VTK_build
cmake ../vtk/
This is how the folder structure is:
├── vtk    
│   ├── vtk       <-- This is the git cloned folder  
│   ├── VTK-Build <-- This is where I'm building  


The header files are in the vtk folder. You can install them and the compiled libraries by building the INSTALL target.

you should follow the build vtk from source and cylinder example, which uses CMake, this has worked for me using gcc on linux.

build VTK (from inside the VTK-Build folder)

cmake -S ../vtk -B .
cmake --build .


download the example from the tutorial site or just create a new folder and put CMakeList.txt and CylinderExample.cxx in it, for brevity i will show only the CMakeLists.txt here, please check the latest docs for an up to date syntax.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12 FATAL_ERROR)

project(CylinderExample)

find_package(VTK COMPONENTS 
  CommonColor
  CommonCore
  FiltersSources
  InteractionStyle
  RenderingContextOpenGL2
  RenderingCore
  RenderingFreeType
  RenderingGL2PSOpenGL2
  RenderingOpenGL2
)

if (NOT VTK_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CylinderExample: Unable to find the VTK build folder.")
endif()

# Prevent a "command line is too long" failure in Windows.
set(CMAKE_NINJA_FORCE_RESPONSE_FILE "ON" CACHE BOOL "Force Ninja to use response files.")
add_executable(CylinderExample MACOSX_BUNDLE CylinderExample.cxx )
  target_link_libraries(CylinderExample PRIVATE ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
)
# vtk_module_autoinit is needed
vtk_module_autoinit(
  TARGETS CylinderExample
  MODULES ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
)


setup your project with cmake and build it

mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DVTK_DIR:PATH=path_to_vtk_build_dir ..
cmake --build .


make sure the built shared objects in the VTK-Build/lib are on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable before running the executable so linux can find and load those shared libraries.

VTK is composed of a lot of shared objects depending on what functionality you want from it, you should follow the rest of the tutorials to know what components you need for a certain functionality and let cmake figure out which shared objects to link.
